# How to delete selection in V-autocomplete vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify v-autocomplete in my project . I can search and bring necessary informations from Api. If we have selection, I want to delete selection after user entered one charecter to input area for a new search.

After enter one charcter choose old selection and delete it.

[image]

```
  <v-autocomplete v-model="studentInfos"
                        :items="studentList"
                        :search-input.sync="searchStudents" 
                         cache-items
                         return-object
                        :menu-props="{ auto: true, overflowY: true,maxWidth:'400px',width:'100%' }"
                        @change="$emit('studentInfos', studentInfos)">
 
            //here is my selection area

            <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
                <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 90%;">
                     <span  class="text-no-wrap">
                        {{ item.Name + ' ' + item.Surname}}
                </span>
           </span>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">  
            //here , api infos
            </template>

        </v-autocomplete>
```

```
    watch: {
        async searchStudents(val) {
            if (value && value.length >= 3) {
                try {
                    this.itemsAirportList = await this.$axios.$get(
                        `api-link/student-search?q=${value}`,
                     );
                 } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }
        },    
    }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with reactjs so I removed the reactjs tag

Comment: Yes I know. MAny react js developers develop vue js thats why i added them to here .

Comment: Okej, but that is misleading so try to stick to the content. You have an Vue issue then only use Vue tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (this.studentInfos&& val && val.length === 1) {
                this.studentInfos= ''
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.searchStudents= val
                }, 100)
            }
```

in here ,if we dont use setttimeout , it gonna delete our first character  also at the same time . So if i send my first character after deletion of selection , it gonna keep first character thx to settimeout function